# Displaying message while waiting to connect to store for IAP

Tags: ios, app-store, in-app-purchase

Over spotty cellular connections, it can take 5 or 10 seconds to connect to the App Store and retrieve prices for my App's IAP.

I'd like to display a nice (non-blocking) message that says that it's connecting so users don't wonder why the store is empty or there are no prices.

I know Apple can get very picky about what you call things.

I'd rather not just say "Connecting..."

Does anyone know of the guidelines for what we can call the App Store for IAPs?

"Connecting to App Store..."

Anyone have any experience with this?  I'd hate to be rejected for a simple wording and have to wait another 2 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

The user might care more about the task at hand, not some technobable about "connecting", whatever that is.

Maybe something more like "Oh, you want buy more frogs?  Let me check and see what frogs are available...",  "Please wait while I catch and weigh your frogs...", "Here are the frogs you can buy...", etc.

To avoid common rejections, make sure to test with no network.  Pull the network cable from your wifi access point, and make sure your IAP does not lock up the UI part way through.